# Any reason why view count is not formatted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Simple question, why is the view count not formatted?

[image]

It is not instantly recoqnizable with bigger numbers, would it be eaiser to read like this

> viewed 230,405 times

Thanks.

Comment: Why does the first related question not come when making the question? The first question in the `Related` menu only came up "AFTER" I made this question. Voted to close.